# How to set ingress-policy to allow limited IP with Istio?

Tags: istio

From the document [Authorization on Ingress Gateway](https://istio.io/v1.7/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-ingress/), I set an ingress-policy as this

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: ingress-policy
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: istio-ingressgateway
  action: ALLOW
  rules:
  - from:
    - source:
       ipBlocks: ["ALLOWED PUBLIC IP HERE"]
```

I got my public IP from [WhatIsMyIPAddress](https://whatismyipaddress.com/), set it in the `ipBlocks` above.

After applied the manifest, when I access my site from browser, it showed `RBAC access denied`.

My applications are deployed in the `default` namespace, is it correct to use `namespace: istio-system` in the metadata? And how to see the access logs for debugging?

What's the right way to set an IP filter?

Check Istio's ingressgateway log got

```
kubectl logs istio-ingressgateway-111111111111-aaaaa -n istio-system
...
[2021-12-20T05:10:58.600Z] "GET /healthz/ready HTTP/1.1" 403 - rbac_access_denied_matched_policy[none] - "-" 0 19 0 - "10.123.45.123" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "11111111-aaaa-3333-cccc-555555555555" "10.123.45.123:30974" "-" outbound|80||demo-service.default.svc.cluster.local - 10.123.45.123:8443 10.148.45.200:22429 - -
[2021-12-20T05:10:58.601Z] "GET /healthz/ready HTTP/1.1" 403 - rbac_access_denied_matched_policy[none] - "-" 0 19 0 - "10.123.45.200" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "22222222-bbbb-4444-dddd-666666666666" "10.123.45.200:30974" "-" outbound|80||demo-service.default.svc.cluster.local - 10.123.45.123:8443 10.123.45.200:15566 - -
2021-12-20T05:29:09.478225Z     info    xdsproxy        connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
```

Why `rbac_access_denied_matched_policy` is `none` here? I'm not using rbac in the K8s cluster. Is it necessary to use it in this case?
[Role Based Access Control (RBAC) Filter](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/rbac_filter)

---

edit

Got new logs from Istio's ingress gateway

```
...
2021-12-21T03:36:41.819072Z     debug   envoy rbac      checking request: requestedServerName: , sourceIP: 10.123.45.111:25965, directRemoteIP: 10.123.45.111:25965, remoteIP: 10.123.45.111:25965,localAddress: 10.123.46.222:8443, ssl: uriSanPeerCertificate: , dnsSanPeerCertificate: , subjectPeerCertificate: , headers: ':authority', '10.123.45.111:30974'
':path', '/healthz/ready'
':method', 'GET'
':scheme', 'https'
'user-agent', 'ELB-HealthChecker/2.0'
'accept-encoding', 'gzip, compressed'
'x-forwarded-for', '10.123.45.111'
'x-forwarded-proto', 'https'
'x-envoy-internal', 'true'
'x-request-id', '123412231a-cb12-9732-859e-0213jladfsj9'
'x-envoy-decorator-operation', 'demo-service.default.svc.cluster.local:80/*'
, dynamicMetadata:
2021-12-21T03:36:41.819091Z     debug   envoy rbac      enforced allowed, matched policy none
```

Comment: A policy applies to the namespace in the metadata/namespace field
https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/security/#policy-target
Can you try to change the namespace to default?

Comment: @Jeroen If use to `default` namespace, all the IPs can access the site. I added some more details to the question.

Comment: You are right since you want to apply it to the ingress gateway, the namespace you use is correct.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak I'm using 1.20.10 k8s version on EKS in AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remote IP address is not passed to the gateway by default. To use the external IP address in your `AuthorizationPolicy` you can change the `externalTrafficPolicy` of the Ingress gateway. For testing you can use the following:

`kubectl patch svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system -p '{"spec":{"externalTrafficPolicy":"Local"}}'`

If this works you should add this to your IstioOperator (or create one) and apply it when installing Istio.

If you don't want to change the TrafficPolicy you might be able to accomplish it by using `remoteIpBlocks` instead of `ipBlocks` in the `AuthorizationPolicy`. But I did not try this yet myself, for reference:
https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-ingress/#ip-based-allow-list-and-deny-list

Comment: The `kubectl patch` command works and how to create an IstioOperator for that? I also tried to modify the current `AuthorizationPolicy` from `ipBlocks` to `remoteIpBlocks`, but the same it doesn't work.

Comment: I got new logs from Istio's ingress gateway and added it to the question. It seems envoy's rbac `matched policy none`.

Comment: @uotn If you don't have an IstioOperator yet, the default profile will be used. 
You can add your own config and apply it while installing Istio. Your config will be merged with the default profile. You can check all the options here:
https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/istio.operator.v1alpha1/
use `istioctl install -f istio-patch.yaml` to apply your config.

Comment: regarding the remoteIpBlocks, I'm not sure how to get those working, you might have to make sure those remote headers are added somehow: "If you are using the X-Forwarded-For HTTP header"

Comment: From [IP-based allow list and deny list](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-ingress/#ip-based-allow-list-and-deny-list) it seems `X-Forwarded-For`'s LB type is `HTTP/HTTPS`. But I'm using EKS so its type should be `TCP Proxy`. `Source of Client IP` is `Proxy Protocol`. I should also use `remoteIpBlocks`. It's right. Not sure what proxy is miss setting.